# import @lingui/loader return empty object

Tags: typescript, linguijs

I am using `lingui` for my translation in my refine app. I a `po` file inside `locales` folder that has some key and the translation like this

```
#: ../internal-tools/pages/dashboard/index.tsx:332
msgid "greeting"
msgstr "Helo"
```

and the function that load the `.po` file is look like this

```
const loadCatalogMessages = async (locale: string) => {
  const { messages } = await import(`@lingui/loader!./locales/id.po`);
  console.log('--- LOAD MESSAGE ---', messages);
  return messages;
}
```

when I try to log it out, it return an empty object. This is strange because I have tried this syntax in another project and it runs without problem

I am expecting the variable `messages` to return the actual result of the `.po` file not an empty object